# Mysql ASC function ORDER only first ID's

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have this line:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM livechat WHERE type='public' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 15") ;
```

And this is for chat, however `ASC` takes only first ID comments, so it shows only 15 old comments (id1, id2 and so on). If I use `DESC` instead of `ASC`, it shows new comments, but in a bad way - newest at the top, since this is a chat, newest comments must be at the bottom.

Comment: Note usual caveats re PHP's mysql_ API

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: ("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM livechat WHERE type='public' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15 ) t order by t.id") ; worked great, you are the man!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM livechat 
    WHERE type='public'
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15
) t
order by t.id")  ;
```

Comment: No code formatting and it's not even valid PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a temporary table that contains the last 15 results, and then ordering from that table.

```
select * from (
    select * from livechat where type='public' order by id desc limit 15
) tmp order by tmp.id asc
```